# Paypal Sandbox API Internal Error

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've been using Paypal Merchant SDK with Sandbox credentials for last few months and everything for working fine.

But today, Im facing this strange problem, whenever I make an API call of SetExpressCheckout, I get **Transaction failed due to internal error** with error code **10001** .. I haven't changed anything in code, it just started to show up.

Im using the github api for transaction: https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php/][1](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php/)

Here is the API Error Response

```
SetExpressCheckoutResponseType Object
(
    [Token] => 
    [Timestamp] => 2013-09-15T07:33:51Z
    [Ack] => Failure
    [CorrelationID] => 1325627aefe46
    [Errors] => Array
    (
        [0] => ErrorType Object
            (
                [ShortMessage] => Internal Error
                [LongMessage] => Transaction failed due to internal error
                [ErrorCode] => 10001
                [SeverityCode] => Error
                [ErrorParameters] => 
            )

    )

    [Version] => 94.0
    [Build] => 7645184
)
```

Comment: Same thing happened to me, except, also our production api (non-sandbox) returns the same error

Comment: Did u find any solution for that?

Comment: Same here on sandbox with PHP Paypal API (and we haven't changed a line of code before it started to happen): [ShortMessage]: string(14) "Internal Error"
[LongMessage]: string(40) "Transaction failed due to internal error"
[ErrorCode]: string(5) "10001"
[SeverityCode]: string(5) "Error"
[ErrorParameters]: null

Comment: Same thing here in Germany. Also cannot connect to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/.

Comment: Is there any information about this issue on paypal site somewhere ? Do you guys know more about this ? I see that it can even happen in production so they should give some info about that on Paypal side...

Comment: @Żabojad, I've checked everywhere but nothing on paypal site at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is your issue. If so PayPal are aware of this issue and are trying to fix it.

https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/event_details?eventId=3945

Update: **Issue with PayPal Website and PayPal APIs - Sep 15 - Sandbox**

**PayPal Notifications**

Sandbox Status Update

Update: We continue to work towards a resolution and will provide an update when we have more information.

Sent Sep 15, 2013 11:24 AM BST by SAR

Start time: Sep 15, 2013 05:55 AM BST

At this time, there is no alternative work-around.

Questions? Please contact by filing a ticket; refer to PP-CRI-3945

Comment: Did they provide any time frame when it'll be fixed?

Comment: @casper123 Sadly no, sorry. I think PayPal didn't expect this one. I'm sure they will have it working in a few hours. If not you can always contact PayPal by filing a ticket; refer to PP-CRI-3945 :D

Comment: @casper123 Mine seems to be working now, Try again, if not clear your cookies and cache

Comment: I'm having this issue in 2017