# Paypal Live transactionSearch API internal error

Tags: paypal, internal-server-error

For certain account transactionSearch API call is giving an internal error.

Its happening only for certain date range.

According to this post
[Paypal Sandbox API Internal Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18810077/paypal-sandbox-api-internal-error)
 the issue is resolved. So raised a new question.

Here is the response

```
ITEMS = Array (@5a4a881)   
    [0] = Object (@786e251)   
        AMT = "21.35"   
        CURRENCYCODE = "USD"   
        EMAIL = "xxx"   
        ERRORCODE = "10001"   
        FEEAMT = "-0.71"   
        LONGMESSAGE = "Internal Error"   
        NAME = "xxx"   
        NETAMT = "20.64"   
        SEVERITYCODE = "Error"   
        SHORTMESSAGE = "Transaction failed due to internal error"   
        STATUS = "Completed"   
        TIMESTAMP = "2013-10-02T19:12:30Z"   
        TIMEZONE = "GMT"   
        TRANSACTIONID = "xxx"   
        TYPE = "Payment"
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

That error could be a lot of different things.  It could simply be a problem with the API servers, but if that's the case it shouldn't continue to happen for a long period of time.  It could be an issue with your API request.  If you want to post a sample of that I'll see if I can find any issue with it.  It could also be that your range is too long or something like that.  Again, post a sample of your request and I'll see if I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: The code is working fine for other accounts. But suddenly its giving this error a particular date range. Its been three days that i am getting this error. Here is the request url https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp?USER=xxx&PWD=xxx&SIGNATURE=xxx&METHOD=transactionSearch&STARTDATE=2013-10-01T20:29:59Z&ENDDATE=2013-10-02T19:29:59Z&VERSION=106.0

Comment: I just tried your string with my API credentials and I got a successful response.

Comment: Yes, the request works fine. But there is one account which is giving this error for the specified date range. Don't know why.

Comment: Sounds like something unique to the account then, which means you'll need to contact PayPal about that one.  You can submit a ticket to www.paypal.com/mts